# Could not see the map in a picture in Android using Map

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am creating a location using a map Activity in android.
Everything is fine on the map, but could not populate the location picture in the map.

MY FULL CODE IS HERE

http://pastebin.com/eTa1eSZe

### Edit:

### After adding V2 , I saw my deice like this: [Output on My phone.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hrIE.png)

I saw one like this:

[image]

But it did not work in my app.

Layout File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="AIzaSyCmEzF1MfGAdfddfddfdf4qyf_MkbyKnoSSNvbO1RFmM"
    />
```

and **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.maptest.googlemaps"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.example.googlemaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <!-- Maps API needs OpenGL ES 2.0. -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
    <!-- End of copy. -->
    <!-- For Google Map -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyCmEzF1MfGAdfddfddfdf4qyf_MkbyKnoSSNvbO1RFmM" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <!-- Give Permission to AutoLife App -->


    <!-- for get the Device IMEI Number -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME_ZONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

    <!-- TODO: package name -->


    <!--
     The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.

    -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <!-- Add Google Map Library -->
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <activity
            android:name=".AndroidGoogleMapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

and Main Java file:

```
package com.maptest.googlemaps;

import java.util.List;

import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

public class AndroidGoogleMapsActivity extends MapActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Displaying Zooming controls
        MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        /**
         * Changing Map Type
         * */
        // mapView.setSatellite(true); // Satellite View
        // mapView.setStreetView(true); // Street View
        // mapView.setTraffic(true); // Traffic view

        /**
         * showing location by Latitude and Longitude
         * */        
        MapController mc = mapView.getController();
        double lat = Double.parseDouble("48.85827758964043");
        double lon = Double.parseDouble("2.294543981552124");
        GeoPoint geoPoint = new GeoPoint((int)(lat * 1E6), (int)(lon * 1E6));
        mc.animateTo(geoPoint);
        mc.setZoom(15);
        mapView.invalidate(); 


        /**
         * Placing Marker
         * */
        List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
        Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mark_red);
        AddItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay = 
             new AddItemizedOverlay(drawable, this);


        OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(geoPoint, "Hello", "Sample Overlay item");

        itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
        mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);

    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Sorry for the whole code post here.
But I am confused.
What is wrong with my code?

I hope you guys can guide me.
Thanks in advance.

### Note:

### I solve the problem, My app key not authorize. when i change package name and create new key. It works.

Comment: have you import googlemap library in your project

Comment: Implement `Google Map API V2`: follow the steps:[https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start)

Comment: yeah, i already import library.

Comment: I am also use V2: but could not see: Here full code; http://pastebin.com/eTa1eSZe

Comment: post ur error log too @user2332049

Comment: I used mapy v2, but I see my device, could not map pictorial form. Check this .[Output On my Device](http://i.imgur.com/8uYYKa4.png) . please check this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this in xml

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
```

to

```
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
```

If ur `API-Key` is right then it should be worked but if not then generate `API-Key` first and replace `API-Key` with newly generated `key` in `manifest`

Comment: when i replace your **class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"**. my app crash. So, if replace **com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment** , then works but could not see pictorial form. I see this in my device.[Output On my Device](http://i.imgur.com/8uYYKa4.png) . please check this.

Comment: I solve the problem, My app key not authorize. when i change package name and create new key. It works.

Answer (score 0):

You are using older map V1 which has been deprecated. Use Google map V2

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Follow this tutorial for new Google map v2

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html